# Javascript overlap with slider causing Bootstrap Column Issues

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, nouislider

I'm trying to have a split between columns and a set of sliders that are laid on top of each other.  The goal is to have the buttons display content via a collapse toggle while having the sliders movable with an image/number tooltip combo so I can have users see what they're dragging while getting the information about the various icons they're sliding.  Here's what happens

- When checked, the column shows 0 or 1-pixel height.
- Javascript for the slider appears but tends to overlay on top of the button content
- When creating spacers for the column, nothing particularly allows the spacing to split to two columns left and right
- When pressing the button for the collapsed div, the content shifts having buttons move around regardless of modification.

[image: THe issue.]

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/10.1.0/nouislider.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/10.1.0/nouislider.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="spacer">
      <div class = 'slider' id='slider1'></div>
      <div class = 'slider' id='slider2'></div>
      <div class = 'slider' id='slider3'> </div>
      <div class = 'slider' id='slider4'> </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
       <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="spacer">

      <button type="button" data-target="#ConditionOne" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse">Healthy</button>
         <div id="ConditionOne" class="collapse">
            None
   </div>

      <button type="button"  data-target="#ConditionTwo" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse">Okay</button>
         <div id="ConditionTwo" class="collapse" >
            &lt;textarea id=&#34;conditionTwoInfo&#34; name=&#34;conditionTwoInfo&#34;&gt;Second Conditional Description&lt;/textarea&gt;
      </div> 
      <button type="button" data-target="#ConditionThree" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse">Not Okay</button>
         <div id="ConditionThree" class="collapse" >
            None
      </div> 

      <button type="button" data-target="#ConditionFour" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse">Dead</button>
         <div id="ConditionFour" class="collapse">
            &lt;textarea id=&#34;conditionFourInfo&#34; name=&#34;conditionFourInfo&#34;&gt;Final Conditional Description&lt;/textarea&gt;
         </div>
      </div>
```

How should I handle both the column issue as well as the button triggering issue as I assume they're tied together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First what I did is get the height of the slider.  From there I hardcoded the slider's height plus an offset

```
.slidespace { height: 275px; //Can be whatever you want
            width: 100% }
```

Used it as a div:

```
 <div class="slidespace">     <div class = 'slider' id='slider1'></div>
      <div class = 'slider' id='slider2'></div>
      <div class = 'slider' id='slider3'> </div>
      <div class = 'slider' id='slider4'> </div>
    </div>
```

This gave me enough space to separate the two.